# Insert date value in SQL table

Tags: sql, date, sql-insert

I have the following table :

```
EMPNO(number), ENAME(varchar), JOB(char), MGR(number), HIREDATE(date), SAL(number), DEPTNO(number)
```

I try to insert the following :

```
insert into EMP_TF1605(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, DEPTNO)
    values(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, 17-DEC-1980, 800, 20);
```

Result :
Error occured. Recheck your SQL statement

I am sure it is the date that is incorrect?

Comment: You need single quotes around the date constant.

Comment: insert into EMP_TF1605
(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, DEPTNO)
values(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, '17-DEC-1980', 800, 20);

Comment: thanks - still giving me the error?

Comment: What error message are you getting? And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Using the online course sqlcourse.com to practice while studying an Oracle chapter - wanted to input the data to practice constraints?  Error is :  Error occured. Recheck your SQL statement

Answer (score 10):

Always use `ANSI` default string literal format for `date` i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` like below.

```
INSERT INTO EMP_TF1605(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, DEPTNO)
VALUES(7369,
       'SMITH',
       'CLERK',
       7902,
       '1980-12-17',
       800,
       20);
```

It will insert your data successfully in most rdbms i.e. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server.

In Oracle, you need to convert it to `date` using function `to_date([value],[format]` prior to insertion as below.

```
INSERT INTO EMP_TF1605(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, DEPTNO)
VALUES(7369,
       'SMITH',
       'CLERK',
       7902,
       to_date('1980-12-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
       800,
       20);
```

However if your input date is in format mentioned in question, you can use `cast` in SQL Server to convert it to `datetime` before insertion as below.

```
INSERT INTO EMP_TF1605(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, DEPTNO)
VALUES(7369,
       'SMITH',
       'CLERK',
       7902,
       cast('17-Dec-1980' AS datetime),
       800,
       20);
```

For other rdbms, you need to look for the equivalent casting functions.

**Update:**

In Oracle, for the date format provided in question, you can use `to_date` to convert your string date literal input along using format `'DD-MON-YYYY'` to data type `date`.

```
TO_DATE('20-SEP-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

You can check demos i.e. **[MySQL](http://rextester.com/IQFAZK30043)**, **[PostgreSQL](http://rextester.com/EKVCGG59047)**, **[SQL Server](http://rextester.com/GCA9134)**, **[Oracle](http://rextester.com/HMO93234)**

Comment: @terrifurness: Kindly accept the answer for future reference :-)

Comment: The best way to express the constant date is `date '2017-09-20'`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in SQL management studio if I use this syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD Report_Date datetime NULL;
GO
Update tablename set Report_Date = cast('2020-01-20' AS datetime)
```

as *zarruq* said previously.

Comment: your answer, however, does little to add new knowledge that was not provided by @zarruq.